# Why are row and column indeces reversed?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, declaration

```
int numberarray[3][5] = {
    {00, 01, 02, 03, 04},
    {10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
    {20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
};
```

why is `number[3][5]` considered as three lists of 5 integers?

If int is a number, and int[3] means a list of 3 numbers, shouldn't int[3][5] be five `int[3]`?

Comment: Please don't abuse tags. Only specify the language you are using.

Comment: there are no 'Lists' in there. int[3] means: an array of 3 int - numbers. and, no, it shouldn't.

Comment: The reason that it works this way *in C* is so that the sizes are in the same order as the indices. That is, if you have `int array[n][m]` and then do `array[i][j]`, then `i` is the index that needs to be less than `n` and `j` is the index that needs to be less than `m`. Note that it does work the way you want in many other languages (including Java, which you originally tagged this question with).

Comment: _"reversed"_ as opposed to [Row- and column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) ?

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
int numberarray[3][5];
```

may be rewritten like

```
int ( numberarray[3] )[5];
```

If you will introduce this typedef

```
typedef int T[5];
```

then the above declaration will look like

```
T numbers[3];
```

So you have an array with `3` elements of the type `int[5]`.

In general of you have an array like

```
T a[N1];
```

then this declaration

```
T a[N2][N1];
```

declares an array of N2 elements of the type T[N1].

This declaration

```
T a[N3][N2][N1];
```

declares and array with N3 elements of the type int[N2][N1]. And so on.

Also pay attention to that in this declaration

```
int numberarray[3][5] = {
    {00, 01, 02, 03, 04},
    {10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
    {20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
};
```

each braced initializer in fact initializes a one-dimensional array with 5 elements. The above declaration can be rewritten like

```
int numberarray[][5] = {
    {00, 01, 02, 03, 04},
    {10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
    {20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
};
```

So within the outer braces there are three braced initializers that can be used to initialize 3 one-dimensional arrays with 5 elements.

So you have `int numberarray[3][5]`.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ the declarations are parsed outwards, starting from the variable name:

```
    arr        // `arr` is...
    arr[3]     // an array of size 3 of...
    arr[3][5]  // arrays of size 5 of...
int arr[3][5]  // int
```